# Bootstrap not working properly. Tried every way I possibly know, but still find no success

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a node js app and to start off I just wanted to create a home page for the login/register. However, when trying to implement bootstrap, I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/journal/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Node.js & Passport App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <%- body %>

  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();



router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));

module.exports = router;
```

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


// Login Page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.send('Login'));

// Register Page
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.send('Register'));

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you try local css and JS? after downloading

Comment: Well, the frontend code seems to work... Where is the backend? Do you use EJS??What does your res.send() or res.end() or res.render() look like?

Comment: @Alpha yes i use EJS. I will post the code.

Comment: can you upload the code to GitHub? It's impossible to tell you what's wrong in your code as we don't even know where the text "Create an account or login" and the 2 links come from. They are not part of your ejs-file and also not part of your 2 js-files.

Comment: Just look up the source code in your browser (Right click and "view source code" or something similar). How does it look like? Is bootstrap included there?

Comment: @Alpha uploading it to github right now.

Comment: @Alpha https://github.com/renwid/node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

It is impossible to help you without seeing the whole code.

You choose the welcome.ejs file here:
[image]

And that file does not contain the bootstrap reference:[image]

So the source code in the browser looks like this (it does not even have an html head or body):
[image]

The question: What exactly are you trying to do?